# Getting the date from a html date input type to a php variable on a different page

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to make a system for my school and some of the code is giving me a problem. i have a teachers page on which i input some details from a database and give a radiobutton with each record. when the user clicks submit it is supposed to go to a different page and put only the records into a differnt table for which the radiobutton was checked. it will put the  the dates that the user has entered into a differnt table. The code for making the date input is

```
 $c=5;
$sd=7;
$ed=11;
echo "<tr> <td>Name</td><td>Number</td><td>Form </td><td> Outings left</td><td>Night outings left</td> <td>Allowed</td><td>Start date</td><td>End Date</td></tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery))
{

echo "<tr> <td>$row[Name]</td><td> $row[Number]</td><td>$row[Form]</td><td> $row[Outings_left]</td><td>$row[Night_outings_left]</td> <td><input type='checkbox' id='$c' name=' $c' value='checked' /></td><td><input type='date' id='$sd' name='$sd' /></td><td><input type='date' id=' $ed ' name=' $ed' /></td></tr>";

$arr= Array($n=> Array(1=>'row[name]', 2=> 'row[number]') );
$c+=5;  
$sd+=7;
$ed+=11;  
}
```

i am trying to read the entered dates in the following way but is not working properly. i just doesnt enter anything into the variable

```
$c=5;
$sd=7;
$ed=11;
for ($ca=1;$ca<$total;$ca++)

    $startdate=$_POST['$sd'];
    echo $startdate;
    $enddate=$_POST['$ed'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the single quotes out of the _POST, since it's reading that as a literal string:

```
$startdate=$_POST[$sd];
echo $startdate;
$enddate=$_POST[$ed];
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use quotes around variables and its a good idea to use this kind of style everywhere ,like:

```
$var = "someText " . $var2 . " someOtherText";<br>
```

instead of

```
$var = "someText $var2 someOtherText";
```